# Swift Parse Query Using A Pointer

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have to query for a class called "Commitment" it has a pointer called "need". I need to be able to access the data in the pointer of need while querying Commitment. I have to query for Commitment because I have to check the "committer" object against the current user. Essentially I want to be able to see the needs that the current user has committed to.

Commitment Class:

[image: ScreenShot]

Need Class:

[image: ScreenShot]

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Commitment")
     query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
    query.whereKey("committer", equalTo:  PFUser.current()!)
    query.includeKey("need")
    query.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {
            self.committment = []
            self.commitObject = []
            for object in objects {

                self.committment.append(Committment(id: object.objectId!, needName: object["needName"] as! String))
                self.commitObject.append(object)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            print("failure")
        }
    }
```

This is my current query. It returns nil on needName so obviously that isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you get **nil** is because you are not accessing the need object but you are trying to get it from the Commitment object
just change your code to something like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Commitment")
     query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
    query.whereKey("committer", equalTo:  PFUser.current()!)
    query.includeKey("need")
    query.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {
            self.committment = []
            self.commitObject = []
            for object in objects {
                let need = object["need"] as [PFObject]?
                self.committment.append(Committment(id: object.objectId!, needName: need["needName"] as! String))
                self.commitObject.append(object)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            print("failure")
        }
    }
```

Notice that i first access the **need** object and from there extract the **needName** property.

BTW! i am not sure that the syntax is 100% accurate (i wrote it in freestyle) but i am sure that you got the idea..

Comment: Thank you! I figured this out a little before you answered!